# Eror importing tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I ran this simple .py:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class Listener(StreanListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Strean(auth, Listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["tour de france"])
```

and i get this error:

```
  File "twe.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tweepy import Stream
  File "/Users/Raz-mac/Documents/tweepy.py", line 1
    git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
```

I'm guessing it's related to importing tweepy?
How could I resolve this?

Comment: did you install it? 

**git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git, 
cd tweepy, 
python setup.py install**

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm using mac osx, and I still get the error even though I installed tweepy (I checked and I have the libraries and tweepy documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following set of actions:

1) Install virtual enviroment (on Linux):
`$ virtualenv env`

2) Run new virtual enviroment
`$ source env/bin/activate`

3) Install tweepy library:
`(env)$ pip install tweepy`

and
everything will be ok:

```
(env)$ python
>>> from tweepy import Stream
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, I've installed virtualenv and created a new environment, activated the environment and ran the same code. I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas why?